# Webview2 Navigation

Tags: c#, webview2

Currently in Webview2 browser if navigated to a particular URL as written below

```
browser.Source = URL;
```

This triggers NavigatingStarting event asynchronously.

How can I trigger a synchronous call for each source being set to trigger the event?

Problem: I am keeping a bool variable to check for the if navigation triggered inside my application and resetting it at the end for the navigatingstarting event. since it is an asynchronous call it is resetting after the first call without the next call being inside my application.

```
void SetBrowserUrl(Uri value)
{
    m_bInsideNavigateCall = true;
    priorsWebBrowser.Source = value;
}
    
void priorsWebBrowser_NavigationStarting(object sender, 
    CoreWebView2NavigationStartingEventArgs e)
{
    if(m_bInsideNavigateCall)
    {
        e.Cancel = false;
        m_bInsideNavigateCall = false; // Reset for next inside call
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Here the issue is if call SetBrowserUrl twice. Navigate starting cancels the second call made because it is not synchronous

Comment: You should post your code. It's not exactly clear what kind of problem you're trying to solve. It looks like you're trying to detect redirections or new navigation events triggered by interactions with HTML elements. But it's just a guess.

Comment: It's not clear what your goal is. The following may (or may not) be helpful: [CoreWebView2.HistoryChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.historychanged?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1150.38)

Comment: added the code in question.
The goal is to prevent Navigation if it's not triggered by my application. Like refresh, back

Comment: Did you check what information `CoreWebView2NavigationStartingEventArgs`  is providing? `IsRedirected`, for example, and the `Url` value. Compare with the `Url` you set instead. -- Don't trust `IsUserInitiated`.

Comment: What about setting `m_bInsideNavigateCall` to false in a `NavigationCompleted` event?

Comment: @PoulBak tried setting m_bInsideNavigateCall to false in a NavigationCompleted event. It didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a list of strings.

```
List<String> insideNavigatingURLS; //Class level variable
```

Just before calling web-browser to navigate, I add the URL to list.

```
  internalURLs.Add(uri.AbsolutePath.ToLower());                     
  webBrowser.Source = uri;
```

In the NavigationStarting Event added a check to see if list contains the navigation url if it doesn't then will cancel the request.

```
void webBrowser_Navigating(object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationStartingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!internalUrls.Contains(e.Uri))  
    {
        e.Cancel = true; 
    }
    else
    {                
        internalUrls.Remove(e.Uri);
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
}
```

So when back or forward navigation is triggered, the list doesn't contain a URL and the navigation request is cancelled